# Implementation of repository method when having multiple datasources

Tags: c#, oop, repository-pattern

I am reading data from CSV file and putting it to the relational database.

If I were to use the repository pattern, how should I implement the GetAll method?
Should it return all data from the database or from the CSV file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have an interface like so:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAll();
   void Save(IEnumerable<MyModel> data);
}
```

Then, you will have:

```
public class CsvRepository: IRepository
{
   IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAll()
  {
    // data from Csv
  }
   void Save(IEnumerable<MyModel> data) 
  {
   // save to csv
  }
}

public class DbRepository: IRepository
{
   IEnumerable<MyModel> GetAll()
  {
    // data from db
  }
   void Save(IEnumerable<MyModel> data) 
  {
   // save to db
  }
}
```

And then you can do sth like:

```
var csv = new CsvRepository();
var db = new DbRepository();

db.Save(csv.GetAll());
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I already had an interface, but didn't thought about the idea to create seperate repositories. :)